# How can I prevent the mobile sdk login screen from appearing as a modal in iOS?

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, modal

I have a Cordova Hybrid mobile app using the Salesforce Mobile SDK v7.0.0. I recently upgraded my macOS as well as changed some other plugins which required me to re-install the Salesforce Mobile SDK plugin. Now the login screen appears as a modal that can be swiped down (see images) and can't be brought back up unless you re-start the app.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Example A: If you log out, the previous in-app screen is still visible. Swiping down on the login shows the old login screen.
[image]

Example B: If you start the app fresh, there is white screen behind it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of the Salesforce Mobile SDK v7.0.0. I upgraded to Salesforce Mobile SDK v7.3.0 and it was fixed.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a change in iOS behavior starting in iOS 13.  But yes this is back to normal in Mobile SDK 7.3, which we released right after iOS 13 was released.